# The store that was requested wasn't found during a clean setup

Tags: magento2, database, setup

During my store setup, I received this error message below.

```
The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.
```

[image: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.]

Why is it happening since the database is empty?

Comment: Do you try to install the magento from the ground? or just migrate the site from dev to prod?

Comment: It's an installation from the ground.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening because you have an environment file created already.

Since you're setting up a project from scratch with an empty database, you can remove it and try to run your setup command again.

```
rm app/etc/env.php
```